How can we evaluate the probability of intelligent life forms existing on other planets?
In popular culture, the sheer size of the universe is taken as evidence to imply that intelligent life forms also likely exist somewhere out there. Given that intelligent life forms evolved here, why not in other planets?
But I’m having trouble understanding this reasoning since a) we don’t even know how life started and b) it is one thing for chemicals to react together to form basic life but a whole different thing to have the exact, right kind of evolutionary process that results in intelligent life forms like us. The latter seems incredibly more improbable, perhaps even unlikely enough for even the sheer size of the universe to not matter.
How do we evaluate the probability or plausibility of life forms similar to us existing or is this completely unknowable?

If popular culture thinks it's likely then it seems to be informed by science.
A lot of scientists thnk that there is intelligent life out there.
Most attempts to evaluate the probability of intelligent life in the universe are concerned with the so called Drake equation. It involves estimates of fractions of stars that have planets and estimates of fractions of planets that are in the habital zone of that star and so on. Since its inception, we have gradually collected more data, for example about the number of exo-planets, and so the estimate is thought to become more reliable.
Estimates, based on data from the Kepler space telescope, of Earth-like planets in our galaxy alone are around 11 billion. Multiply that by the estimated galaxies in the visible Universe (roughly 2 trillion) and you get a pretty big number of places where there may be life. It would be foolish to believe there's no one out there.
Other fields such as exobiology and evolutionary biology have also been useful in updating the Drake equation. Hypotheses of how to tackle the problem of abiogenesis are giving us more insight in possible pathways of complex replicating molecules (RNA world) to simple single cell life. The fact that the earliest life forms developed some 3.7 billion years ago is also encouraging.
Your trouble understanding this reasoning, as you call it, and hence adopting the argument of incredulity has most likely to do with how bad human intuition generally is when it comes to (really) large numbers and Bayesian statistics.

The argument of incredulity only applies  if one can show demonstrative evidence of a claim and the response is “well I can’t imagine it to be that way.” You have not demonstrated any evidence of life existing anywhere else and have merely asserted it to be foolish. Pointing out there are tons of planets isn’t evidence of intelligent life elsewhere in the universe. We still don’t know how life originated, and even then, even if the probability of life is small, surely the probability of intelligent life is miles and leagues smaller. Life does not necessitate the intelligent kind

I apologise if I offended you. I hope you will read up on the Drake's equation and some of the science behind what I tried to explain. It is very interesting.

@Syed What kind of answer were you looking for? Had I arrived a few moments earlier I would have answered pretty much the same way. We have no evidence either way for the existence/nonexistence of alien life. We couldn’t communicate with it even if it were right next to us for a bunch of reasons, anyway. You’re sort of asking for how to evaluate its probability of existence, but the comment seems to suggest that you already know that we can’t know that.
